# Proper line editing when using node.js for terminal app

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

I am making a command line interface to a Forth system running on an Arduino Nano using node.jsr.  I am finding when trying to edit a line before accepting it with the enter key that I get unexpected results.  When I press the left or right arrow keys I get ^[[D and ^[[C respectively rather than the cursor moving left or right.  The following code provides an example:

```
process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
    process.stdout.write(data)
});
```

If you run the above code, type a few characters then try to move back with the left arrow, ^[[D shows up rather than the cursor moving to the left.  Does anyone know how to correct this behaviour?

Comment: Normally I'd look towards curses for this, and there is mcurses for arduino, but I've no idea what there is that is arduino compatible and that also has Node.js bindings.

Comment: Its from the computer side not Arduino side that I am having the issue with.  Its when I am writing a command, before hitting enter to send it to the Arduino.  If I make a mistake, I have to backspace everything else written to remove the error rather then use the arrow keys to move to it and delete it like normal on the terminal.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/curses

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed

Comment: Thanks for the response Quentin.  I have played with blessed before and have been hacking around with blessed-xterm to see if I can get rid of my issue.